# What is an obstacle identification surface and why would a pilot intentionally penetrate it during an ILS approach?

Tags: instrument-procedures, ils, precision-approach

What is an obstacle identification surface?

Why would a pilot intentionally penetrate it during an ILS approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obstacle Identification Surfaces apply to departures and the portion of an non-precision IAP beyond the Visual Descent Point. If you are in the clouds, you should never penetrate the OIS on departure.

On arrival, the VDP assures obstacle clearance with a normal approach to landing. ILS only approaches do not have a VDP depicted so there is no OIS to penetrate. (The glide slope takes you right to the touchdown zone.) ILS/LOC (and Localizer only) approaches do have a VDP for the non-precision version of the approach. You could penetrate the OIC on a localizer approach and if that happens, visibility minimums are increased as explained in the last paragraph from the AIM below.

AC 150-5300-13-c12 Airport Design has a good visualization of the departure OIC.
(As an aside, it has lots of charts and graphs showing how departures and approaches are designed.)

[image: obstacle identification surface]

**AIM 5−2−8. Instrument Departure Procedures (DP) − Obstacle Departure Procedures (ODP) and Standard Instrument Departures (SID)**

> …if an obstacle penetrates what is called the 40:1 obstacle
> identification surface, then the procedure designer chooses whether
> to:
>
> 1. Establish a steeper than normal climb gradient; or
> 2. Establish a steeper than normal climb gradient with an alternative that increases takeoff minima to allow the pilot to visually remain
>    clear of the obstacle( s); or
> 3. Design and publish a specific departure route; or
> 4. A combination or all of the above.
> 5. The 40:1 obstacle identification surface (OIS) begins at the departure end of runway (DER) and slopes upward at 152 FPNM until
>    reaching the minimum IFR altitude or entering the en route structure.
>    This assessment area is limited to 25 NM from the airport in
>    nonmountainous areas and 46 NM in designated mountainous areas. Beyond
>    this distance, the pilot is responsible for obstacle clearance if not
>    operating on a published route, if below (having not reached) the MEA
>    or MOCA of a published route, or an ATC assigned altitude. See FIG
>    5−2−1. (Ref 14 CFR 91.177 for further information on en route
>    altitudes.)

**5−4−5. Instrument Approach Procedure (IAP) Charts**

> h. The Visual Descent Point (VDP), identified by the symbol (V), is a
> defined point on the final approach course of a nonprecision
> straight−in approach procedure from which a stabilized visual descent
> from the MDA to the runway touchdown point may be commenced. The pilot
> should not descend below the MDA prior to reaching the VDP.
>
> i. A visual segment obstruction evaluation is accomplished during
> procedure design on all IAPs. Obstacles (both lighted and unlighted)
> are allowed to penetrate the **visual segment obstacle identification
> surfaces**. Identified obstacle penetrations may cause restrictions to
> instrument approach operations which may include an increased approach
> visibility requirement, not publishing a VDP, and/or prohibiting night
> instrument operations to the runway. There is no implicit obstacle
> protection from the MDA/DA to the touchdown point. Accordingly, it is
> the responsibility of the pilot to visually acquire and avoid
> obstacles below the MDA/DA during transition to landing.

**Edit**: This AIM is consistent with what the **Instrument Procedures Handbook** says about non-precision approaches but not consistent with what the handbook says about the potential for obstacles on ILS approaches.

p 7-9

> ...if an *ILS is configured with approach lights* **or** a nonprecision
> approach is configured with either MALSR, SSALR,or ALSF-1 lighting
> configurations and the procedure has a published visibility of 3/4 SM
> or greater, a penetration of the final approach OIS may exist. Also,
> pilots will be unable to determine whether there are penetrations of
> the final approach OIS if a nonprecision procedure does not have
> approach lights, or is configured with ODALS,MALS, or SSALS/SALS
> lighting since the minimum published visibility will be 3/4SM or
> greater.
>
> As a rule of thumb, approaches with published
> visibilities of 3/4SM or more should be regarded as having final
> approach OIS penetrations and care must be taken to avoid any
> obstacles in the visual segment. Approaches with published
> visibilities of 1/2 SM or less are free of OIS penetrations...

Comment: Verbatim knowledge test question: ***"How can the pilot determine, for an ILS runway equipped with MALSR, that there may be a penetration of the obstacle identification surfaces (OIS), and care should be taken in the visual segment to avoid any obstacles?"*** This conflicts with your statement that it doesn't apply to ILS.

Comment: @RyanMortensen I am quoting directly from the AIM and noting that I cannot find any ILS only approaches with a VDP. In my judgement, around 5% of the Knowledge Test questions are either wrong or misleading or have contradictory answers. This appears to be one. I made an edit to reflect what they want on the test.

Comment: I agree that this addition completes the answer.  I would like to note for others' reference that a 1:40 rise/run or 152Ft per NM rise is a 1.43 degree slope angle.  Well below the standard 3.0 glide slope.

Comment: I think the key statement from your entire answer is, "**There is no implicit obstacle protection from the MDA/DA to the touchdown point.**"

Comment: I'd also like to add that 152ft/NM is only the obstacle ID surface, not the expected standard minimum climb gradient of 200ft/NM giving a clearance gain of 48ft/NM. And added to that, the OIS starts way out at the tippy end while the standard climbs/descents intersect the 35ft threshold crossing height or landing zone.

Comment: For vertically guided approaches between DA and threshold see "vertical guidance surface" VGS FAA order 8260.3D (was called GQS in 8260.3B, changed in .3C without explanation) it is a surface that ensures no maneuvering around obstacles will be needed for straight-in approaches, it is allowed to be penetrated by some frangible equipment required for operations like radar reflectors and approach lights. Wheel crossing height is considered for the size-category of aircraft to be served. It seems VGS is also being applied to some non-precision approaches now.